# Wamp disable display errors

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I didn't want display the error of my code in a browser.

With wamp i disabled **display errors**  in  Wamp -> PHP -> Php setting -> display errors but when I refresh my page i have an error message not a blank page !

[image: error messsage]

There is my simple code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Display error</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>HelloWorld</h1>

    <?php
        echo "J'affiche une phrase avec php";

        echo "je créer une erreur"

        echo "hello";



    ?>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can disable error display, but your code still won't run in case of Fatal errors. Rather fix your syntax problems first.

Comment: And to add to @mario's comment above, did you restart your WAMP server after changing the setting?

Comment: Yes i restart, with warning it's work, not with fatal errors like @mario say.

Comment: Disabling errors is a lot less effective than fixing them.  Errors and warning exist for a reason, they're the interpreter's way of telling you that something is wrong.  Ignoring them won't make it right.

Answer (score 0):

It's **browser** who renders you this page.
What's the problem with it?

Comment: not a problem, i just don't understand why i didn't have a blank page. Just because it's a fatal error, it's ok now i understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        echo "J'affiche une phrase avec php";

        echo "je créer une erreur" <--you forgot the ;. that is why you have errors. keep error_reporting on to see what you are doing wrong :)

        echo "hello";



    ?>
```